# Maven multimodule project - parallel run of unit tests

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven project that consists of ~30 modules. 4 of these modules contains a large number of junit tests in separate testcases, so when I'm running tests all modules except these are executed quickly, but each of these modules running separately could take several minutes. What I want to achieve is

1. When project is compiled I want to use as much threads as CPUs available (-T1C)
2. When tests are running I want to use as much threads as CPUs available, and I want to run testcases in all modules as parallel as possible, but not more than number of CPUs. If I just run tests with -T1C it assign thread per module, so tests inside long-running modules are not running in parallel. But if I set forkCount=1C in long-running modules each of them occupies as many threads as CPUs are, so when all of them are running CPUs are overused. I know that I can set up something like forkCount=0.5C but in this case it will be required to manually adjust these numbers.

So is it a way to specify some build-level limitation having everything else as parallel as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of surefire plugin, Junit framework etc. do you use? Please show your pom file / configuraiton etc.?

Comment: junit is 5.6.3 and surefire is 3.5.0-M5

Comment: First Junit is Junit Jupiter (which should be upgraded to latest version 5.9.1) and also you should upgrade surefire to 3.0.0-M7 and you have to check the configuration for parallelization in Junit Jupiter https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

Comment: You can get the number of processors available by using: int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();